# How to open a file on the desktop c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop

Im very new to code and i would like to know how do i link a button in visual studio to open a file on your desktop? `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/Desktop");`
Doesent work
Help please :D

Comment: You are missing the username `"C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/<filename>"`. You can get the path to the current user desktop with this: `string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`

Comment: can you gimme an exaple please?

Comment: Do you want to open a folder? Or do you want  to show a dialog for user to open a file on certain folder? Or do you want to read the file content?

Comment: folder in a folder

Answer (score 1):

Here is your desired example:

```
// Get the desktop folder path of the current user
string folderpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)‌​;
// define the filename of the file you want to open
string filename = "desktop.ini";
// Get the full path of the folder and filename combined. Path.Combine will add slash automatically
string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, filename);
// Open the file with the defined filepath
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
```

Comment: I changed my example. I forgot to rename path variable and using system.io for Path.Combine.

Comment: You only have to replace the filename "desktop.ini" with the desired filename which is on your desktop.